# CSS background from SVG image not showing gradients

Tags: css, svg

Missing gradient parts of SVG image when used as element background. Chrome (FF also) is removing gradient parts from SVG if CSS is in separate file from HTML, if style is inlined in to HTML image load with the gradient parts. Why is that and how to make it load?

In CSS file declared:

```css
.img-feature-best {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3c?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?%3e%3csvg width='31px' height='36px' viewBox='0 0 31 36' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cdesc%3eCreated with Lunacy%3c/desc%3e%3cdefs%3e%3clinearGradient x1='1' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1' id='gradient_1'%3e%3cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23FF8278' /%3e%3cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23FFE38A' /%3e%3c/linearGradient%3e%3c/defs%3e%3cpath d='M3.46036 0L0.109737 6.61911C-0.0513606 6.93714 -0.0340615 7.31499 0.154877 7.61726C0.344357 7.91927 0.677905 8.10326 1.03767 8.10326L6.07793 8.10326L9.10203 12.0865C9.29854 12.3463 9.60695 12.4967 9.93158 12.4967C10.3627 12.4967 10.7025 12.2425 10.8603 11.93L14.0177 5.69145C9.74885 5.28824 5.98522 3.14987 3.46036 0Z' transform='translate(0 22.7533)' id='Path' fill='url(../StyleSheets/%23gradient_1)' stroke='none' /%3e%3cpath d='M13.9079 6.61911L10.5573 0C8.03246 3.14987 4.26883 5.28824 0 5.69145L3.15763 11.93C3.31521 12.2425 3.65498 12.4967 4.0861 12.4967C4.41073 12.4967 4.71941 12.3463 4.91592 12.0865L7.93975 8.10326L12.98 8.10326C13.3398 8.10326 13.6733 7.91927 13.8628 7.61726C14.0517 7.31499 14.069 6.93714 13.9079 6.61911L13.9079 6.61911Z' transform='translate(16.96484 22.7533)' id='Path' fill='url(../StyleSheets/%23gradient_1)' stroke='none' /%3e%3cpath d='M26.5347 13.1068C26.5347 5.87971 20.583 0 13.2673 0C5.9517 0 0 5.87971 0 13.1068C0 20.3337 5.9517 26.2137 13.2673 26.2137C20.583 26.2137 26.5347 20.334 26.5347 13.1068ZM14.8372 18.5983C14.8372 19.1647 14.3726 19.6237 13.7993 19.6237C13.2262 19.6237 12.7613 19.1647 12.7613 18.5983L12.7613 10.1033L11.2244 11.6326C10.8206 12.0345 10.1635 12.0369 9.7567 11.6376C9.3499 11.2387 9.34746 10.5896 9.75129 10.1877L13.0627 6.89281C13.359 6.59801 13.806 6.50883 14.1947 6.66718C14.5834 6.82552 14.8372 7.1999 14.8372 7.61513L14.8372 18.5983Z' transform='translate(2.222656 0.25)' id='Shape' fill='%23FF3E7E' stroke='none' /%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Chrome DevTools element CSS show:

```css
.img-feature-best {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3c?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?%3e%3csvg width='31px' height='36px' viewBox='0 0 31 36' version='1.1' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3e%3cdesc%3eCreated with Lunacy%3c/desc%3e%3cdefs%3e%3clinearGradient x1='1' y1='0' x2='0' y2='1' id='gradient_1'%3e%3cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23FF8278' /%3e%3cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23FFE38A' /%3e%3c/linearGradient%3e%3c/defs%3e%3cpath d='M3.46036 0L0.109737 6.61911C-0.0513606 6.93714 -0.0340615 7.31499 0.154877 7.61726C0.344357 7.91927 0.677905 8.10326 1.03767 8.10326L6.07793 8.10326L9.10203 12.0865C9.29854 12.3463 9.60695 12.4967 9.93158 12.4967C10.3627 12.4967 10.7025 12.2425 10.8603 11.93L14.0177 5.69145C9.74885 5.28824 5.98522 3.14987 3.46036 0Z' transform='translate(0 22.7533)' id='Shape' fill='%23FF3E7E' stroke='none' /%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

Missing part:

```
id='Path' fill='url(../StyleSheets/%23gradient_1)' stroke='none' /%3e%3cpath d='M13.9079 6.61911L10.5573 0C8.03246 3.14987 4.26883 5.28824 0 5.69145L3.15763 11.93C3.31521 12.2425 3.65498 12.4967 4.0861 12.4967C4.41073 12.4967 4.71941 12.3463 4.91592 12.0865L7.93975 8.10326L12.98 8.10326C13.3398 8.10326 13.6733 7.91927 13.8628 7.61726C14.0517 7.31499 14.069 6.93714 13.9079 6.61911L13.9079 6.61911Z' transform='translate(16.96484 22.7533)' id='Path' fill='url(../StyleSheets/%23gradient_1)' stroke='none' /%3e%3cpath d='M26.5347 13.1068C26.5347 5.87971 20.583 0 13.2673 0C5.9517 0 0 5.87971 0 13.1068C0 20.3337 5.9517 26.2137 13.2673 26.2137C20.583 26.2137 26.5347 20.334 26.5347 13.1068ZM14.8372 18.5983C14.8372 19.1647 14.3726 19.6237 13.7993 19.6237C13.2262 19.6237 12.7613 19.1647 12.7613 18.5983L12.7613 10.1033L11.2244 11.6326C10.8206 12.0345 10.1635 12.0369 9.7567 11.6376C9.3499 11.2387 9.34746 10.5896 9.75129 10.1877L13.0627 6.89281C13.359 6.59801 13.806 6.50883 14.1947 6.66718C14.5834 6.82552 14.8372 7.1999 14.8372 7.61513L14.8372 18.5983Z' transform='translate(2.222656 0.25)'
```

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work. You'll have to do this `fill='url(%23gradient_1)'` where gradient_1 is the one defined in the defs.

Comment: background-image data must be entirely self contained. You can't have external accesses to other files such as something in a Stylesheets directory

Comment: What I need is just SVG image with gradient parts. I guess it is possible to do SVG image with gradient without external resources? This must be specifics how SVG gets exported?